# SSRS Report subscription not saving changes

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS report that scheduled to send once a day at 9PM. Every time I try modifying the recipients, they revert back to the e-mail address for the person that created the report.

It's only displaying that in SSRS, if i check the subscriptions in the the ReportServer database, it shows the correct recipient list (It's not showing those that are CC'ed though). It also says that on the last run it sent to each of the recipients intended to be on the report.

I've tried modifying it a few times already, CC'ing myself on the report, but I haven't received the report once and the recipient list keeps reverting back. I deleted the report and re-created it from scratch but the same thing occurs.

I also have some reports that say it was sent on schedule to all the recipients, but the e-mail never comes through. Looking through the ExecutionLogStorage table it also seem to show that it was sent on schedule.

Comment: "Every time i try modifying the recipients, they revert back to the e-mail address for the person that created the report..." => Who created the subscription? Your user or somebody else? If it is somebody else, does your user have the `Manage all subscriptions` task?

Comment: Currently i created the report and the subscription with my account; I saved the copy of the report in a different directory in SSRS. The original 1 was also recreated and saved in the original directory...When i look at the subscription the status says it sent to the recipient list, but when i go to edit it shows the old user that created the report...

Comment: If I were you I would add the report again and recreate the subscription from scratch. If everything works as expected, then delete the other reports.

Comment: I did exactly that; It seems the recipients revert the next day or when the report is schedule to send; I'll take another look after the report is supposed to send and will update. I setup a second subscription to send at the current time and it came through fine...